Incorrect Post URLs
My site was recently hacked with some unrecognised plugins added.  These have been removed and I have added wordfence to update security.  However I now find the URLs for all my posts have changed.  I can no longer ‘view post’ when I try. The URL for each post no longer refers to the post # but the post year.
I would appreciate any help I can get to get my site working properly.
https://michaelandpamstravels.com/

I have checked the URLs and found that the Post URLs becomes https://michaelandpamstravels.com/?page_id=15204. Looks like your website permalink structure sets to Plain.
To correct this I suggest you to go to Settings > Permalinks >
Permalink structure, here you can update Permalink structure as per your need.
Screenshot : https://ibb.co/t8tzFZJ
